# How do you encode with AVVideoCodecH264 codec using AVAssetExportSession?

Tags: swift, video-encoding, avasset

I currently have the code below to compress a video after selection

```
func compressVideo(inputURL: NSURL, outputURL: NSURL, handler:(session: AVAssetExportSession)-> Void)
{
    var urlAsset = AVURLAsset(URL: inputURL, options: nil)

    var exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: urlAsset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality) // AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)

    exportSession!.outputURL = outputURL
    exportSession!.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4 //AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
    exportSession!.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
    exportSession!.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler { () -> Void in

        handler(session: exportSession!)
    }

}
```

Which works fine is there any way to re-encode the selected video into AVVideoCodecH264 or something? As the audio playback on HTML5 players (non-safari) or Android phones has the audio off.

> The video file itself was in the .mov format exported from Snapchat
>   and the audio sync shows when there is a photo clips within the video.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: It seems `AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality` (and a few others) auto-use h.264 as per framework comments. https://github.com/theos/sdks/blob/master/iPhoneOS10.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Headers/AVAssetExportSession.h